# Migdal's problem about rotating a particle in a magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

I was given a problem by my professor, which belongs to Migdal. The problem is as follows:

> If a particle is rotated by 2$\pi$ in a magnetic field its
>   wave-function $\psi$ transforms into $\exp(i\phi A) \psi$, 
>   where $\phi$ is given by the perimeter of the circle, while if the
>   field were that of a strong force, $\phi$ is given by the area of
>   the circle.

Can anybody refer me to the paper where all these are calculated? I'll appreciate your answers.

However, just explaining why $\psi$ transforms into $\exp(i\phi A) \psi$, will be a great help (suppose the case of magnetic field).

Comment: Comment to the post (v6): It seems the various editors wildly disagree which tags to use! Reviewers: If you are thinking of voting-to-close, please consult the original version (v1) first.

Comment: Cannot your professor point you in the right direction?

Comment: @N.S. Googling something lame like "magnetic field migdal" brought up this page: https://books.google.com/books?id=Fe--p45zFnkC&pg=PA309&lpg=PA309&dq=magnetic+field+migdal&source=bl&ots=M2Z_bS4HF-&sig=tsff0OrZPCykyiisOIl9nmrV6eI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinkev_nKTOAhXG7yYKHeOwB9sQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=magnetic%20field%20migdal&f=false. Ref. therein might be what you are looking for, but it's been published in Moscow, likely in Russian.

Answer (score 1):

The phase change of a charge particle moving in a magnetic field is usually obtained by a gauge argument. [See section 5.4 of this paper which discusses the Aharanov-Bohm effect.](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_charged.pdf) Using simple arguments you can deduce the perimeter law for the phase, e.g., the phase picked up is $i(2\pi r)A$ (see the equation on page 49). I work in condensed matter physics so I do not know the corresponding argument for the strong force, but I imagine it is similarly a geometric picture and can be deduced from an appropriate gauge transformation.